# Numpy: fuzzy 'greater_than' operator, working on list of values (requesting advices on existing code)

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I have implemented a numpy function that:

- takes as inputs:

  - a n (rows) x m (columns) array of floats.
  - a `threshold` (float)
- for each row:

  - if the max value of the row is larger than or equal to `threshold`,
  - if this max value is not preceded in the same row by a min value lower than or equal to `-threshold`,
  - then this row is flagged `True` (larger than),
  - else this row is flagged `False` (not larger than)
- returns then this n (rows) x 1 (column) array of booleans

What I have implemented works (at least on provided example), but I am far from being an expert in numpy, and I wonder if there is no more efficient way of handling this (possibly avoid the miscellaneous `transpose` & `tile` for instance?)
I would gladly accept any advice on how making this function more efficient and/or readable.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Test data
threshold=0.02       #2%
df = pd.DataFrame({'variation_1': [0.01, 0.02, 0.005, -0.02, -0.01, -0.01],
                   'variation_2': [-0.01, 0.08, 0.08, 0.01, -0.02, 0.01],
                   'variation_3': [0.005, -0.03, -0.03, 0.002, 0.025, -0.03],
                  })

data = df.values
```

Checking expected results:

```py
In [75]: df
Out[75]: 
   variation_1  variation_2  variation_3   # Expecting
0        0.010        -0.01        0.005   # False (no value larger than threshold)
1        0.020         0.08       -0.030   # True (1st value equal to threshold)
2        0.005         0.08       -0.030   # True (2nd value larger than threshold)
3       -0.020         0.01        0.002   # False (no value larger than threshold)
4       -0.010        -0.02        0.025   # False (2nd value lower than -threshold)
5       -0.010         0.01       -0.030   # False (no value larger than threshold)
```

Current function.

```py
def greater_than(data: np.ndarray, threshold: float) -> np.ndarray:
    # Step 1.
    # Filtering out from 'low_max' mask the rows which 'max' is not greater than or equal
    # to 'threshold'. 'low_max' is reshaped like input array for use in next step.
    data_max = np.amax(data, axis=1)
    low_max = np.transpose([data_max >= threshold] * data.shape[1])
    
    # Step 2.
    # Filtering values preceding max of each row
    max_idx = np.argmax(data, axis=1)                   # Get idx of max.
    max_idx = np.transpose([max_idx] * data.shape[1])   # Reshape like input array.
    # Create an array of index.
    idx_array = np.tile(np.arange(data.shape[1]), (data.shape[0],1))
    # Keep indices lower than index of max for each row, and filter out rows with
    # a max too low vs 'threshold' (from step 1).
    mask_max = (idx_array <= max_idx) & (low_max)
    
    # Step 3.
    # On a masked array re-using mask from step 2 to filter out unqualifying values,
    # filter out rows with a 'min' preceding the 'max' and that are lower than or
    # equal to '-threshold'. 
    data = np.ma.array(data, mask=~mask_max)
    data_min = np.amin(data, axis=1)
    mask_min = data_min > -threshold
    
    # Return 'mask_min', filling masked values with 'False'.
    return np.ma.filled(mask_min, False)
```

Results.

```py
res = greater_than(data, threshold)
In [78]:res
Out[78]: array([False,  True,  True, False, False, False])
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
lesser = data <= -threshold
greater = data >= threshold

idx_lesser = np.argmax(lesser, axis=1)
idx_greater = np.argmax(greater, axis=1)

has_lesser = np.any(lesser, axis=1)
has_greater = np.any(greater, axis=1)

outptut = has_greater * (has_lesser * (idx_lesser > idx_greater) + np.logical_not(has_lesser))
```

yields your expected output on your data and should be quite fast. Also, I'm not entirely sure I understand your explanation so if this doesn't work on your actual data let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dominik. your proposal is very neat / readable, much better than mine. This is frustrating somehow: I am very good at making things more complex than they are... Ah ah, thanks again!